# No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"items"} missing required keys: [:id]

Tags: ruby-on-rails

> Update: I've been trying to debug my files, so most of the files have changed recently

I am getting a strange error when trying to use a "new" action to my `items_controller`. Essentially, a `wishlist has_many items` and an `item belongs_to wishlist`. The error message is as follows:

[image: UrlGenerationError]

### Code

Here is my `items_controller`:

```
class ItemsController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @item = Item.find(params[:id])
  end
  def new
    @item = Item.new
  end
  def create
   @item = Item.new(item_params)
    if @item.save
      redirect_to "/wishlist", :notice => "Success!"
    else
      redirect_to "/wishlist", :notice => "Failure, try again later!"
    end
  end
  def edit
    @item = Item.find(params[:id])
  end
  def update
    @item = Item.find(params[:id])
    if @item.update_attributes(item_params)
      redirect_to(:action => 'show', :id => @item.id)
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end
  private
  def item_params
    params.require(:item).permit(:name,:size,:qty,:priority)
  end
  private
  def create_params
    params.require(:item).permit(:name,:size,:qty,:priority,:wishlist_id)
  end
end
```

And my `routes.rb`:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get '/wishlist' => 'wishlists#index', as: :wishlists
  get '/wishlist/:id' => 'wishlists#show', as: :wishlist
  get '/wishlist_items/new' => 'items#new'
  get '/wishlist_items/:id' => 'items#show', as: :items
  get '/wishlist_items/:id/edit' => 'items#edit', as: :edit_items
  patch '/wishlist_items/:id' => 'items#update'
  resources :items
```

And finally, my `new.html.erb` for the `items` model:

```
<h1>New Item</h1>
<div class="wishlist-new">
    <% if true %>
    <%= form_for(@item) do |f| %>
        <%= f.text_field :name, :placeholder => "Name" %>
        <%= f.text_field :size, :placeholder => "Specifications" %>
        <%= f.text_field :qty, :placeholder => "Quantity" %>
        <%= f.text_field :priority, :placeholder => "Priority" %>
        <%= f.text_field :id, :placeholder => "Wishlist ID" %> # changing :id to :wishlist_id doesn't seem to do anything
        <%= f.submit "Create Item", class: "btn-submit" %>
    <% end %>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

My migration files (so you know how my databases are structured:

```
# Migration file for items
class CreateItems < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    drop_table :items
    create_table :items do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.string :size
      t.string :qty
      t.integer :priority
      t.references :wishlist
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end

# Migration File for Wishlists
class CreateWishlists < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    drop_table :wishlists
    create_table :wishlists do |t|
      t.string :title
      t.timestamps
    end
  end 
end
```

### Attempts to Debug

It seems like the `routes.rb` is sending requests to different methods in the `items_controller` because the error seems to say that `/wishlist_items/new` is accessing a `show` method even though its `new` method takes priority. To support this, the page loads properly when I comment out `get '/wishlist_items/:id' => 'items#show', as: :items` in the routes file. What happens is the page loads properly, and the Item is created properly (when I fill out the form) *except* that when I go into the console, it says that the Item created has a property of `wishlist_id: nil` even though I specified for it to be `1` in the form.

The method mentioned above has two problems: (1) it doesn't work entirely correctly, and (2) it becomes impossible to `show` a specific Item in the wishlist.

---

> The error occurs *before* the inner section of the `form_for` is loaded, so the problem either is (a) a weird routing thing (as mentioned above) or (b) something weird happening to the `@item` variable.

---

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what is the path you are visiting? Why are your `wishlist_items` routes (`as: items`) overriding your `items` routes?

Comment: Is the controller file called **item_controller.rb** and not **items_controller.rb**? What is your `rake routes` output?

Comment: Oh shoot, the `as :items` definitely looks problematic.

Comment: What is wrong with it?

Comment: It's called `items_controller.rb`

Comment: Comment out this line: `get '/wishlist_items/:id' => 'items#show', as: :items` and see if that gets rid the `UrlGenerationError`. Something weird might be going on with the path helper that the `form_for` call is using because of your `as: items` option. If that works, then you can probably just set the path as an option in the `form_for` call and uncomment the route.

Comment: Maybe <%= form_for([@wishlist, @item]) do |f| %>

Comment: That gives the same error as in the question.

Comment: I have changed the post, so disregard anything I have said before this